# "MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER (0x8004011D)" error message. When i am trying to access an Exchange Server 2013 mailbox by using a MFCMAPI utility.

Tags: outlook, mapi, exchange-server-2013

I have installed Exchange server version 2013. Then I tried to create and connect to the server using `MFCMAPI` tool manually. While login to the message store it throws the following error

```
"Error: 
Code: MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER == 0x8004011D
Function CallOpenMsgStore( lpMAPISession, (ULONG_PTR)m_hWnd, lpEntryID, ulFlags, (LPMDB*)lppMAPIProp)
File MainDlg.cpp
Line 437 "
```

And i had gone through to the article given below and followed the instructions given in the same. But, now also i get the same `"MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER == 0x8004011D"`error as before.

link : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2013/05/21/how-to-mfcmapi-create-mapi-profile-exchange-2013.aspx

Please help me to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Problem:`
You will get this error message if the Outlook profile is in the Cache mode.

`Solution:`
On the client computer, open the Control Panel and click the Mail icon.
Open the `<Profile>`, click the email account and select the related `<Account>`.
Click Change.
Verify that the Use `Cached Exchange Mode box` is unchecked.

Comment: Amit, I am not installed outlook in my machine. I am using MFCMAPI tool in Exchange server installed server machine. By using that tool i can able to create a profile, but, unable to login. While try to login Initially it shows "Your Microsoft exchange Server is unavailable.... " error prompt with (retry, workoffline, cancel). Nothing done if i select retry option. When i select workoffline it show failon provider error message. Note: the mailbox name is resolved with domain name. My Exchange server version is 2013.  Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: If you have liberty to recycle these 2 services: "Microsoft Exchange Information Store" and "Microsoft Exchange Active Directory Topology". Restart these services and check "Microsoft Exchange Transport" must be running on exchange server. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: Hi Amit, thank you for your suggestion. This is live Exchange server could you please tell the reason to restart the service. And also share me anything else does i need to check in the server Or anything does i need to change in the configuration. So, that it will be easier to analyse the issue and restart the service. Awaiting for your reply.

Comment: This is the issue because of caching. So store services recycle will work. And if you are sure about the creds but still not able to login AD services recycle might help. Most important your transport services should be up.

Comment: Before restart the Exchange server I need to let you know that i'm using the Exchange MAPICDO as mail client. Further to test this case I found that we can able to login the profile which is created  through outlook for the same user. But, we can't do the same using MAPICDO.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange 2013 only allows ROH (RPC-over-HTTP) connections. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2014/01/16/create-outlook-profile-exchange-2013.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2014/01/17/how-create-outlook-profile-office-365.aspx for the steps on how to create ROH profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found that the link on dave vespas blog is pointing to an old version of mapicdo.

Make sure you have the latest version of mapicdo & mfcmapi and try again.